# Does a Macedonian need a visa to visit the UK if she has a 5 year resident visa in the EU?

Tags: visas, uk, macedonian-citizens

I live in Germany and have an EU passport; my wife is here with me. She is from Macedonia but  she has received a five year resident visa. I would like to know if she needs a visa to visit the UK. We are planning to go for four days in March for a football match. We have already purchased plane tickets, made reservations for a hotel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for youre super answer yes my wife have this kard you sad before but i apply on yhe net and they giving her termin for intervju in macedonoia and thats a problem the payment for the visa is not an isue any advice.?

Answer (score 5):

**Bad news**: The visa policy of the UK is separate from that of the Schengen countries, so having a German residence permit will not in itself allow your wife to enter the UK.

**Good news**: However, as an EU citizen your right to free movement within the EU includes a right to travel to the UK *with your family*, so as long as your wife travels *with you*, she should have the right to enter the UK without a visa if she has a German residence card headed "Residence card of a family member of a union citizen". (Which she should if you're *not* German; if you *are* German she has to apply for a visa, but can't be required to furnish other documentation than for the legitimacy of your marriage).

**Bad news**: The UK government has refused to implement this part of the Freedom of Movement directive.

**Good news**: In December 2014 the European Court of Justice ruled that they have to.

**Confusing news**: It is not clear to me whether this has caused a change of actual practice at the border yet.

What this means to you is that to play it safe, your wife should apply for a vistor visa to the UK. Be sure to note at the time of applying that she is the spouse of an EU citizen traveling with her; I think the UK does honor the part of the rules saying that the visa application fee should be waived in that case.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2023, after Brexit?